# How to take the number of occurrences of a number in a list and create a new list that has the occurrence number and the original number after it?

Tags: python, list, function

I am given a list to put into a function. The function is then suppose to return the amount of times each number was in the function. So for example, if the given list is [15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7], the output list should be [3,15,3,6,2,7].

```
def encode_rle(flat_data):
    set_list = set(flat_data)
    flat_data_converted = []
    for value in set_list:
        flat_data_converted.append(value)
    list = []
    for number in flat_data_converted:
        amount = flat_data.count(number)
        list.append(amount)

    new_list = flat_data_converted + list
```

This is what I have done so far, but the numbers in the list are not attached to their occurrence amount.

Comment: What should be the output of `[15,1,15]` ?

Comment: [1,15,1,1,1,15]

Comment: RLE in function name suggest OP is doing [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def encode_rle(flat_data):
    result = []
    i = 0
    n = len(flat_data)
    while i < n:
        count = 1
        while i + 1 < n and flat_data[i] == flat_data[i + 1]:
            count += 1
            i += 1
        result.extend([count, flat_data[i]])
        i += 1
    return result

flat_data = [15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7]
print(flat_data)
print(encode_rle(flat_data))
```

Expected output: `[3, 15, 3, 6, 2, 7]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```py
from itertools import groupby

lst = [15, 15, 15, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7]

out = []
for value, group in groupby(lst):
    out.extend([sum(1 for _ in group), value])

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 15, 3, 6, 2, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to over-complicate things, you can use one `for-loop` to achieve your goal:

```
def encode_rle(flat_data):
    if not flat_data:
        return []

    new_lst = [1]
    for idx in range(1, len(flat_data)):
        if flat_data[idx] == flat_data[idx - 1]:
            new_lst[-1] += 1
        else:
            new_lst += flat_data[idx - 1], 1
    return new_lst + [flat_data[-1]]
        

print(encode_rle([15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7]))
print(encode_rle([15, 1, 15]))
```

### Output:

```
[3, 15, 3, 6, 2, 7]
[1, 15, 1, 1, 1, 15]
```

The code above:

1. Check if the list is empty
2. Set a counter at the last cell of the new list and adds one to it (first element of the list)
3. Loop through the rest of the list:

   - If the value is equal to the one before it adds one to the counter.
   - Else it adds the previous value to the list and starts new counting.
4. Adds the last value to the list and returns it.

---

In addition, in your code you used: `list = []`.

It is generally a bad practice to name variables after reserved words in the language, like `list`.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too vague. are the same numbers always next to each other or can they be spread? i.e: is it always `[15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7]` or can it be `[15,6,7,15,6,7,15,6]`?

If they're always next to each other you can do:

```
lst = [15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7]

def convert(lst):
    output = []
    n = lst[0] # start with the first number
    count = 1
    for number in lst[1:]: # iterate through all other numbers
        if number == n: # if the new number is the same as the old one, increment the count
            count += 1
        else: #if you found a new number, add the current count and number to output and updated n
            output.append(count)
            output.append(n)
            n = number
            count = 1
    # at the end of the loop since all the numbers were the same, you still need to add the final result to the output
    output.append(count)
    output.append(number)
    return output

print(convert(lst))
```

if not, you need to use a dictionary to count each number's occurrence:

```
lst = [15,6,7,15,6,7,15,6]

def convert(lst):
    occurances = {}
    for number in lst:
        if number in occurances: # if we have already encountered this number, incerement its count:
            occurances[number] += 1
        else: # if it's a new number, set its count to 1
            occurances[number] = 1
        # this can be simplified using python's default dict but I coded it like this so it's easy to understand
    output = []
    for number in occurances:
        output.append(occurances[number])
        output.append(number)
    return output

print(convert(lst))
```

if there is an upper bound on the numbers you encounter (for example if the max value is 1000 or less) you can create a list using `counts = [0]*MAX_NUMBER` and then just increment the value at the index of each number. This is usually done with dealing with ASCII characters since using an array (list) with direct indexing is faster than using a dictionary but it won't work well for larger `MAX_NUMBER` values since it uses a lot of memory.

I know these solutions aren't the shortest but they are easy to understand and more efficient than the posted solutions as they don't do multiple passes over the data (although I suspect the itertools solution might be faster since it's using C++, but algorithmically speaking it's still slower since it does one pass for grouping and then some needless conversion to get the length of the group. You can always achieve the same performance by writing your own C++ extension in something like Cython).

Answer (score 0):

Using the [more-itertools](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.run_length) package, you can do it easily.

```python
from more_itertools import run_length, flatten

def encode_rle(flat_data):
    return list(flatten([b,a] for a,b in run_length.encode(flat_data)))
```

Examples:

```python
print(encode_rle([15,15,15,6,6,6,7,7]))
[3, 15, 3, 6, 2, 7]

print(encode_rle([15,1,15]))
[1, 15, 1, 1, 1, 15]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recursion:

```
def encode_rle(flat_data):
    if len(flat_data) <= 1:
        return [1] * len(flat_data) + flat_data
    else:
        encoded_list = encode_rle(flat_data[1:])
        if flat_data[0] == encoded_list[1]:
            encoded_list[0]+=1
        else:
            encoded_list = [1, flat_data[0]] + encoded_list
        return encoded_list
```